# KVO for property of another class

Tags: objective-c, ios

I would like to add observer in my UIViewController for property in my application delegate.

is it possible like below code?

```
myAppDelegate *appDelegate = (myAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]                                         ;


    [self addObserver:self
           forKeyPath:appDelegate.currentLocation
              options:0
              context:nil];
```

the issue it expect the value for "forKeyPath" to be NSString.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
myAppDelegate *appDelegate = (myAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]                                        ;

[appDelegate addObserver:self
              forKeyPath:@"currentLocation"
                 options:0
                 context:nil];
```